# Why is it "when" and not "then" in Wilfred Owen's poem? What is the meaning with "when"?

Tags: word-meaning, poetry

From *[The Calls](http://ww1lit.nsms.ox.ac.uk/ww1lit/collections/item/3352)* by Owen:

> Stern bells annoy the rooks and doves at ten.
>   I watch the verger close the doors, and **when**
>   I hear the organ moan the first amen,
>       Sing my religion's---same as pigeons'.

Why isn't it **then**?

I'm not very sure what the meaning is with **when**.

"When I hear the organ moan the first amen, [I start to] sing my religion [is the same] as [the religion of the] pigeon"?

If it were **then**, the meaning would have been more clear: after the verger closes the door, the organ moans the amen that says "my religion is the same as that of the pigeon".

Comment: Do you take "religion's" to be "religion is"?

Comment: @TRomano - yes. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't know. I find the punctuation of the line rather cryptic. The dash is possibly to show ellipsis of **the**.  That would comport with "religion is".

Comment: @TRomano - there must have been some popular ditty at that time with those words. Or maybe it was a saying, a by-word popular then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It needs to be **when**, my singing is dependent upon the organ starting to play.

```
When I hear the organ [I] sing
```

this does not work with **then**

```
Then I hear the organ [I] sing
```

I'd also claim that immediate clarity is not always a poet's intent. To puzzle over the phrasing, to savour the choice of words, to untangle the meaning or meanings is part of the joy of reading poetry.

Comment: Thank you! I memorized the poem a couple of years ago, and always recalled it as **then**. I never thought that it is Owen himself who starts to sing. Probably there was a ditty with these words, "my religion's same as pigeon's", I'll try googling.